# Partitioning to install linux along side windows (Dual-boot)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

Here's how my partitions look like:

```
/dev/sda
 free space    1 MB
 /dev/sda1    ntfs    471 MB    398 MB
 /dev/sda2    efi    104 MB    33 MB    
    Windows Boot Manager
 /dev/sda3    16 MB    unknown
 /dev/sda4    ntfs    127440 MB    90236 MB
 free space    0 MB
/dev/sdb
 free space    250059 MB
```

As you can see I have a 128 GB SSD with windows installed on and a 250 GB SSD which I'm about to install linux on.

1. I'm going to set a primary partition for root and assign 64 GB and Ext4 to it, an extended partition for /home and assign it as logical and set 128 GB with Ext4 and another extended partition for swap, logical, 16 GB, at the end of the free space and again Ext4; is this correct?
2. I have 58 GB free space left do I need to assign it to some mount points like /boot or /tmp or /usr etc. ?
3. Device for boot loader installation:
   where should I install it? an article on the internet suggested if I install it on a partition other than where windows is installed I have to assign linux manually in MBR so what's the best course of action here?
   .

Comment: What did you search for? Could you share the link and text you are refering to?

Comment: @sancho.s I've been watching vide, reading others' questions and many articles all about partitioning, but here's the one that I mentioned in the question [link](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/how-to-install-ubuntu/)

Comment: I also chose 16 GB for swap because I have 16 GB of RAM, this will allow me to hibernate I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, You have Windows is in EFI mode, thus gpt disks not MBR disks. BE sure your Ubuntu installer boots in EFI mode. you will have much difficulty if you install ubuntu in Legacy mode.

Second, 64GB is really too much for /. Make 20-30 GB for /, 16 GB swap (if you hibernate), and the rest for /home. All will be primary partitions since GPT does not need or use extended partitions.

Third, the EFI bootloader should be installed to the EFI partition (sda2) on the primary disk if both are internal drives. The installer will take care of this automatically.

Comment: I'm sure I didn't do anything that would lead me to installing in legacy mode and I made a bootable USB flash with UNetbootin so I guees I'm fine, but my question is, I plan to install lots of games and sofware, where do these install on?  / or /home ? for example if I install wine and then install huge games like 60GB+ do I need space on / or /home?

Comment: @Shayan -- wine prefixes will be in your home partition. turn off legacy support in the firmware settings to ensure an EFI boot

Comment: @ravey thanks, also what happens if I install the bootloader on sda instead of sda2?

Comment: you can't, if you booted in EFI mode the installer will put it in the EFI partition  you told it to use. IF it is asking where to put it you are in Legacy mode.

Comment: I read this article  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI and disabled legacy mode (Bios/CSM) in the firmware of laptop. I hope this works!

Comment: ok, so the system chooses /dev/sda to install bootloader by default, should I change to sda2? I made sure I'm in EFI mode.

Comment: the system chooses sda2 by default